# How to take in account children for :nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some simple html

```
<div>row1</div>
<div>row2</div>
<div>row3</div>
<div>
    <div>row4.1</div>
    <div>
        <div>row4.2.1</div>
        <div>row4.2.2</div>
    </div>
    <div>row4.3</div>
    <div>row4.4</div>
</div>
<div>row5</div>
```

and css file

```
div:nth-child(even)
{
   background-color:green;    
}
```

I want to make all odd rows green and to not take care of hierarchy. But in result I have  this

[image]

What am I doing wrong? how to make green rows 2, 4.1, 4.2.2 and 4.4. All other shoud be white.

Is it possible without javascript by css only?

Comment: at first glance - it is doing what you asked - it should color the even rows - which are 2 and 4 - and it's coloring all 4.*** divs because they are div 4 children. Since the parent div is getting background-color: green, I guess all the children are going to inherit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're describing is strictly not possible with CSS selectors.

The `:nth-child` selector (like `:nth-of-type`) only operates within the context of a single isolated group of children (not descendants). And indeed, that is exactly what you're seeing: the even *children* of each parent being highlighted. As you've written that selector, it will match rows 2, 4 (i.e. the parent of all rows 4.x), 4.2 (i.e. the parent of all rows 4.2.x), and 4.4, because they are each even-indexed children of their parents.

I'm afraid your options are (as I see it):

- Flattening the DOM so that all of the rows are children of the same parent element. I suspect this might not be possible in your application.
- Manually specifying whether a row is highlighted using JS and some sort of `.highlighted` CSS class. Not hard, but also kinda annoying to keep up to date if rows are added/removed/moved. Can be easily accomplished in jQuery by adding a `.row` CSS class to each row and using `$('.row:even').addClass('highlighted');`. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39q22/1/). The jQuery-less method is more verbose but also quite simple.
- Creating a vertically-repeating background image (or set of evenly-spaced divs) for the line highlights. If you know the height of each line beforehand, you can simply create a 1px-wide image with twice the height of the row. Highlight the bottom half of the image and set the background image to repeat. On the one hand, this can be done entirely in CSS (especially with inline base64-encoded images). On the other hand, it can't handle variable-height rows.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no it is not possible. CSS doesn't work by counting the elements in the document. It treats the document as a tree and you can't treat it any other way.

Your options are to remove the nesting (which ruins the semantics), to style the individual elements (with a class, say, perhaps dynamically generated) or to use Javascript.

One other thing you could do to make it make sense is to add this:

```
div {
    background-color: white;
}
```

[This is better](http://jsfiddle.net/39q22/) but still not quite what you want.

Comment: If you use JQuery, you can get all the div element and add a class for the even element : https://www.inkling.com/read/jquery-cookbook-cody-lindley-1st/chapter-3/recipe-3-1

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Solution for this is to using a class, provided your html structure is not a large.

```
<div>row1</div>
<div class="green">row2</div>
<div>row3</div>
<div>
    <div class="green">row4.1</div>
    <div>
        <div>row4.2.1</div>
        <div class="green">row4.2.2</div>
    </div>
    <div>row4.3</div>
    <div class="green">row4.4</div>
</div>
<div>row5</div>

<style>
div.green
{
   background-color:green;    
}
div {
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
```